# How to open all programs/files shortcuts within a folder

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I'm trying to open all programs simultaneously as shown in the picture below which are shortcuts:

[image]

> **Note:** Every single one of the shortcuts listed in the image, is installed in its own, separate directory if that matters any.

---

### **What I tried**

I've tried several different things after research and testing with some online solutions first; however, I can't seem to find any way to get this to work properly with such a task as I describe.

- *Selecting all* and pressing `ENTER` but that only opens one, single instance.

  - Same results when *selecting all* and clicking `Open`
- From the [Batch file to execute all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250567/batch-file-to-execute-all-files-in-a-folder) post I tried:

  - > for %%i in (C:\macros\Day*) do %%i

    - It just opens the first instance, and opens the other only after the first one is closed. Same for the rest of the files too, I have to close the opened one to get the following one to open.

---

### Question

Is it in any way possible to do this sort of task through CMD or any other method?

Comment: @LPChip Tried with two, only 1 opens still.

Comment: Try using [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) --> `for %%i in ("C:\macros\Day\*") DO start "" "%%~i"` or [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) --> `for %%i in ("C:\macros\Day\*") DO CALL "%%~i"`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) in the `for` loop and had to prefix a backslash before the asterisk in the folder path and then it worked as expected. I should be able to use this same method with [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) as well if I wanted too and I'm told I could incorporate a [timeout](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) delay as well if needed.

### Script Commands

- `for %%i in (C:\macros\Day\*) do start "" "%%~i"`
- `for %%i in (C:\macros\Day\*) do call "%%~i"`
- `for %%i in (C:\macros\Day\*) do start "" "%%~i" && timeout /t 5`
- `for %%i in (C:\macros\Day\*) do call "%%~i" && timeout /t 5`